# Android: Java.lang.String cannot be converted to JsonArray

Tags: java, android, json

This is my android code. When I am trying to parse my jsonArray it gives me an error that string cannot be converted to Jsonarray through my response is json array:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        tv1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        DefaultOAuthConsumer defaultOAuthConsumer  = new DefaultOAuthConsumer("my consumer key","my secret key");

        //REQUEST URL
        String url = "http://back.unaux.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products";

        RequestQueue requestQueue;
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        try {
            url = defaultOAuthConsumer.sign(url);
            Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonArrayRequest req=new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Error"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(req);
    }
}
```

This is my response for json

```
[
   {
      "id":685,
      "name":"Caramel-min",
      "slug":"caramel-min",
      "permalink":"http:\/\/back.unaux.com\/product\/caramel-min\/",
      "date_created":"2017-09-26T18:56:01",
      "date_created_gmt":"2017-09-26T18:56:01",
      "date_modified":"2017-09-27T12:27:56",
      "date_modified_gmt":"2017-09-27T12:27:56",
      "type":"variable",
      "status":"publish",
      "featured":false,
      "catalog_visibility":"visible",
      "description":"",
      "short_description":"",
      "sku":"",
      "price":"350",
      "regular_price":"350",
      "sale_price":"",
      "date_on_sale_from":null,
      "date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,
      "date_on_sale_to":null,
      "date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,
      "price_html":"<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#8377;<\/span>350.00<\/span> &ndash; <span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#8377;<\/span>500.00<\/span>",
      "on_sale":false,
      "purchasable":true,
      "total_sales":2,
      "virtual":false,
      "downloadable":false,
      "downloads":[

      ],
      "download_limit":-1,
      "download_expiry":-1,
      "external_url":"",
      "button_text":"",
      "tax_status":"taxable",
      "tax_class":"",
      "manage_stock":false,
      "stock_quantity":null,
      "in_stock":true,
      "backorders":"no",
      "backorders_allowed":false,
      "backordered":false,
      "sold_individually":false,
      "weight":"1.0",
      "dimensions":{
         "length":"",
         "width":"",
         "height":""
      },
      "shipping_required":true,
      "shipping_taxable":true,
      "shipping_class":"",
      "shipping_class_id":0,
      "reviews_allowed":true,
      "average_rating":"0.00",
      "rating_count":0,
      "related_ids":[

      ],
      "upsell_ids":[

      ],
      "cross_sell_ids":[

      ],
      "parent_id":0,
      "purchase_note":"",
      "categories":[
         {
            "id":43,
            "name":"Chocolate",
            "slug":"chocolate"
         }
      ],
      "tags":[

      ],
      "images":[
         {
            "id":710,
            "date_created":"2017-09-27T12:25:19",
            "date_created_gmt":"2017-09-27T12:25:19",
            "date_modified":"2017-09-27T12:25:19",
            "date_modified_gmt":"2017-09-27T12:25:19",
            "src":"http:\/\/back.unaux.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/08\/Caramel-min-1.jpg",
            "name":"Caramel-min-1",
            "alt":"",
            "position":0
         },
         {
            "id":710,
            "date_created":"2017-09-27T12:25:19",
            "date_created_gmt":"2017-09-27T12:25:19",
            "date_modified":"2017-09-27T12:25:19",
            "date_modified_gmt":"2017-09-27T12:25:19",
            "src":"http:\/\/back.unaux.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/08\/Caramel-min-1.jpg",
            "name":"Caramel-min-1",
            "alt":"",
            "position":1
         }
      ],
      "attributes":[
         {
            "id":0,
            "name":"Kg",
            "position":0,
            "visible":true,
            "variation":true,
            "options":[
               "1\/2",
               "1.0",
               "2.0",
               "3.0",
               "4.0",
               "5.0"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "default_attributes":[

      ],
      "variations":[
         705,
         704
      ],
      "grouped_products":[

      ],
      "menu_order":0,
      "meta_data":[
         {
            "id":1369,
            "key":"_vc_post_settings",
            "value":{
               "vc_grid_id":[

               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "id":1404,
            "key":"slide_template",
            "value":"default"
         }
      ],
      "_links":{
         "self":[
            {
               "href":"http:\/\/back.unaux.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products\/685"
            }
         ],
         "collection":[
            {
               "href":"http:\/\/back.unaux.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: pls post your stack trace

Comment: If i understand right, try String.valueOf(response) ?

Comment: Yes, please post your stacktrace

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: You are trying to parse a XML/HTML instead of JSON, probably this is a InternalServerError page. Debug and test the URL in browser.

Comment: My Url is correct because if i execute it manually in my browser it works fine, however if i execute the same url in android it gives me error, so i guess the issue is regarding parsing. @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: Read your stacktrace, you are trying to parse a XML, not a JSON

Comment: Yeah I understand, but why is it returning html instead of json because when i use the same url in browser it returns me json

Comment: issue was completed or not ?

Comment: Not yet @parikdhakan, Please provide me a solution if you have

Answer (score -1):

> **you have array inside array.Test like that :** add volley library
>
> oncreate(){
>
> sendRequest(); }
>
> ```
> private void sendRequest() {
>     try {
>         StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(test_urls,
>                 new Response.Listener<String>() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onResponse(String response) {
>                         Log.e("respnose", "" + response);
>                         parseJSON(response);
>                     }
>                 },
>                 new Response.ErrorListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>                         progressDialog.dismiss();
>                         Toast.makeText(Page_details_bkp.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                     }
>                 });
>
>         RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Page_details_bkp.this);
>         requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         progressDialog.dismiss();
>         Log.e("sendreq:", e.toString());
>     }
> }
>
>
> public void parseJSON(String json) {
>     JSONObject jsonObject = null;
>     try {
>         jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
>         users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
>         try {
>             userID = jsonObject.getString("api_status");
>             //ids = new String[jsonArray.length()];
>             if (userID.equals("success")) {
>                 ids = new String[users.length()];
>                 names = new String[users.length()];
>                 emails = new String[users.length()];
>                 sub_images1 = new String[users.length()][3];
>                 sub_ids = new String[users.length()][3];
>                 // images = new String[users.length()];
>                 //log.e("length :", users.length() + "");
>                 for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
>
>                     JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
>                     ids[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
>                     names[i] = jo.getString(KEY_NAME);
>                     emails[i] = jo.getString(KEY_EMAIL);
>
>                     try {
>                         JSONObject locArrObj = users.getJSONObject(i); // cotains one "out" array
>                         JSONArray conferenceLocArr = locArrObj.getJSONArray("posts");
>                         if (conferenceLocArr.length() > 0) {
>                             // this array has two objects and each object has array
>                             JSONObject o = null;
>                             for (int ii = 0; ii < conferenceLocArr.length(); ii++) {
>                                 o = conferenceLocArr.getJSONObject(ii); // it has one array
>                                 try {
>                                     // if (!o.getString("image").equals("")) {
>                                     sub_images1[i][ii] = o.getString("image");
>                                     sub_ids[i][ii] = o.getString("id");
>
>                                     //log.e("Main response:", ids[i] + "," + ids[i] + "," + names[i] + "," + emails[i]);
>
>                                     //}
>                                 } catch (JSONException e) {
>                                     e.printStackTrace();
>                                     //log.e("sub response:", e.toString());
>                                 }
>                                 // sub_images1[i] = o.getString("image");
>                                 //  do your work with Stage 1 and guests
>                                 // and for second object for Stage 2 and guests.
>                             }
>                             Categories movie = new Categories(ids[i], names[i], emails[i], "2015", sub_images1[i][0],
> ```
>
> sub_ids[i][0], sub_images1[i][1], sub_ids[i][1], sub_images1[i][2],
>   sub_ids[i][2]);
>                                   movieList.add(movie);
>                               }
>                           } catch (JSONException e) {
>                               //log.e("response:", e.toString());
>                               e.printStackTrace();
>                           }
>                       }
>
> ```
>             } else {
>             }
>         } catch (JSONException e) {
>             //log.e("response:", e.toString());
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } finally {
>             prepareMovieData();
>         }
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         //log.e("parse:", e.toString());
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you @parik dhakan, I'll give it a try